# Save objects in MemCache instead of Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have built an app using google app engine. The app works fine, but am currently thinking of optimizing it, and in particular I've heard of this concept of persisting objects to `memcache` instead of the datastore, as a means of quickly acessing frequently needed data.

Assume I have objects of this model:

```
class Ea(db.Model):  
    name = db.StringProperty()  
    code = db.StringProperty()
```

And I have say the following instance I want to keep in `memcache`

```
myea = Ea.new(name='John',code='@jo')
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 5):

If you care about the data, you should first write it to the datastore.  You can invalidate the cache pre-write, then, depending on your application, recache post-write or on the first read.

Check out Nick's post on [efficiently memcaching models](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Efficient-model-memcaching); he presents a nice pattern, and will help you avoid some common issues.

Comment: well, I do intend to commit to the datastore, but I wanted to know how to commit to memcache too, for increased performance.

Comment: @mcnemesis, see the article I referenced.  It has a step-by-step walkthrough of what you're looking for.  Nick also explains some of the issues with the naïve approach.

Comment: how does that pattern handle concurrency? I don't see anything transactional going on there.  It seems like you could have super stale data in memcache with the wrong order of operations...

Comment: @peter, memcache is not transactional.  How you invalidate / update the cache depends on the needs of your application.  Two common patterns: following the write, either update the cache or delete the key from cache (so it will be re-read when needed).  If you're asking about preventing a 'query storm' in the event of a cache miss, that is a little trickier.

Comment: @Robert the safest approach to ensure that memcache doesn't contain stale data is the sequence (delete from memcache, add/update datastore, optionally add to memcache). If you delete/update from memcache after the datastore write, you might fail the memcache update.

Comment: @TimDelaney Note that I said you can invalidate the cache pre-write, and depending on your application, re-add it post-write.  Since the Python runtime now supports CAS, you can make the process more robust as well.

Comment: @Robert Sorry - the way you phrased it sounded like you meant that deleting the key from cache should be done *after* the write.

Answer (score 0):

The link specified by Robert Kluin works for db based model. For ndb based models you can use this.

```
def ndb_entity_to_protobuf(e):
    return ndb.ModelAdapter().entity_to_pb(e).Encode()

def protobuf_to_ndb_entity(pb):
    # precondition: model class must be imported
    return ndb.ModelAdapter().pb_to_entity(entity_pb.EntityProto(pb))
```